# Is there a way to right-click Windows taskbar icons (minimized or not) and mute/unmute them?

Tags: windows, audio, taskbar, context-menu

Is there a native way or a 3rd-party app that allows me to right-click taskbar icons, minimized or not, and get a mute/unmute button for them at the subsequent dropdown menu that follows (the one that has the option to pin them to the taskbar or close them if they're already open)? This would be similar to how you can right-click Google Chrome tabs and mute/unmute sites in them. Hopefully even show which app is playing music if one wishes to have that.

Bonus question: Is there a way to manage the audio channels the same way? For example, make one app's audio play on my headphones and one in my speakers and then maybe switch their places?

I've tried installing EarTrumpet which accomplishes most of these functions but that's an audio mixer per se while what I'm after is having the functionalities on the drop-down menu that issues after the right-click.

Comment: We don't do "bonus questions" here. We require a single question per post so that a single answer can be authoritatively correct. If you have more than one question, make more than one post. Edit your post and choose a single question to keep, otherwise this post may be closed for being too broad.

Comment: "We don't do 'bonus questions' here." can sound pretty authoritative to a new user. Feel free to close this post and if you happen to have administrative rights also close my account. I doubt my activity will be long if such encounters happen often.

Comment: I am only a member of the community. The Help section does lay out how this site works and explains most of the biggest differentiators between this Q&A format and more familiar (perhaps) forum, where multiple questions and open ended discussion are more normal. My attempt was to conversational. I apologize that it did not come across that way. This site is different for real reasons. I found it difficult to learn those differences and value them years ago when I started out here, but this site has been, by far, the most helpful to me of any source online.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Android, on Windows, applications are not tagged nor ask permissions for various resources (Except for Windows Store Apps).  Since the OS has very little knowledge of the functionality of each application, it can not show you arbitrary context menus.  The menus have to be built into the applications.

Comment: I see. But the possibility to control individual audio sources from a single control point does exist because the native sound mixer does precisely that. Isn't there a way to preserve the same functionality as a newly added option in the already existing context menus? Or are you telling me you can't modify the current behavior of the context menus in any way at all?

Comment: You're conflating things. Applications don't need to be on the taskbar in order to generate sound. The volume mixed captures activity from the audio-processing portions of the system. The taskbar is based on a specific subset of applications that are designed to work a particular way inside Windows. The two are not the same thing. Context menus can be modified, but there is nothing inherent in Windows applications that correlates the elements of a taskbar icon and audio behavior. Such a solution could probably be developed, but it is not native, and so far we're not aware of such a tool.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Even though I'd hope to find a specific solution (be that native or not) this answers all my doubts I had about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you right-click the Sound icon in the traybar, not that of
the application, to see a menu. Select "Open Volume mixer"
in order to control the sound-usage of all running applications.

You may in the Volume mixer change the volume of each application
separately or that of Windows in general. You may also click on the
volume icon below each application to mute or unmute it.

See this article for more information with screenshots:
[How to open the Sound and Volume Mixer in Windows 11/10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-new-windows-7-volume-mixer-control).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer but I'm specifically looking for a way on how to interact with the audio from the taskbar's icons' context menus.

Comment: Sorry, but that just doesn't exist on Windows.